# About renderItem in FlatList -> React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, youtube, flatlist

I'm just curious about rendering multiple item in FlatList...
I'm using carousel to show my images with one youtube-iframe on item.

Expected Behavior is while I'm playing the youtube, if I scroll to the other side, it should stop playing but it still plays by itself. Is it better to improve my method or is there any way to apply multiple items to render in FlatList?

My initial code looks like this

```
image_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <ItemImage
    marginLeft={6}
    source={item.store_img}
    type={'store_dtl'}
    ref={(ref) => this.row['image' + index] = ref}
    videoId={item.ytb_link}
    pressItem={item}
    pressIndex={index}
    onPress={()=> this.pressItem(item,index)}/>


 );


<Carousel
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.image_renderItem}
          inactiveSlideScale={1} 
          sliderWidth={CmmUtil.getWidth()}
          itemWidth={CmmUtil.getWidth() - 36}
          onSnapToItem={(index) => {
            if (index > 0) {
              if (this.row['image' + 0].isPlaying()) {
                this.row['image' + 0].togglePlaying();
              }
            }
          }}></Carousel>
```

in Item image, it renders images and youtube video. I just want to stop the youtube playing when carousel snaps to next item or when it does not stays on youtube image.

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you using a FlatList or a Carousel?

Comment: I'm using carousel to show image List